# How to process all portions delimited with $ $ with MathJax-node?

Tags: node.js, express, mathjax

I am developing a math web page. There are formulas written in LaTeX that must be rendered. When I use MathJax in the client side, that is, referencing it in the HTML header like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.7/latest.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>
```

Then, once the page is loaded, I can run the function *MathJax.Hub.Typeset()* to convert all LaTeX formulas delimited between two $ to HTML code.

But now I was trying to use MathJax-node, which is an API for MathJax functions on the server side. So, I created an HTTP server with the framework *Express* that receives a string, invokes the MathJax with that API, and returns the HTML code.

The problem is that it does not extract those portions delimited with $ $ as the other version does, so I had to create a loop separating those portions, converting one by one, and then concatenating the results.

I want to know if there is some way to do that automatically.

I think the problem comes because in the configuration I cannot add the extension "tex2jax.js". Notice I have it commented. If I uncomment it, the server console throws an error:

```
var mjAPI = require("mathjax-node");
mjAPI.config({
    MathJax: {
        //extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
        jax: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"],
        displayAlign: "left",
        tex2jax: {inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],processEscapes: true,},
        TeX: {extensions: ["AMSmath.js","AMSsymbols.js"]},

    },
});
mjAPI.start();
```

This is the error thrown when I discomment the "extensions" line (it is thrown when I try to start the server):

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')
```

If instead I keep the configuration above and try to pass the entire markdown to MathJax, including those that are not delimited by $ $, then when calling it, it throws the error:

```
TeX parse error: Extra close brace or missing open brace

node:internal/errors:477
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

And the server stops.

I also want to point out that the MathJax version that is used in MathJax-node is the 2.7.9. The newer versions 3.x are not appropiated for my web page because I want the user to be able to select parts of the formulas with the mouse, which is not possible with 3.x versions.

Comment: You have a system design decision to firm up:  Do you want the server to render the markdown into HTML and transmit the rendered HTML to the browser?  Or do you want the markdown to be transmitted to the browser and have the browser render the markdown into HTML locally?    **Both** are possible with MathJax.  Either way though, you'll end up with a MathJax object that gets configured with things like its delimiters (the `$`'s).  All this is described very well in the [documentation](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/index.html) though, so I'm not sure where things went wrong for you.

Comment: @Wyck I updated my question putting the configuration I am using, the errors, and the MathJax version.

Comment: Ok, just seeing this issue, it seems that it is not possible: https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-node/issues/423

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [mathjax-node-page](https://github.com/pkra/mathjax-node-page)?